# $L^2$ = $L$ equality implications for a formal language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

Let's say I have a formal language $L$. I wanted to know which of these three equalities can be derived from the the given fact that $L^2$ = $L$:

1. $L^+  = L$
2. $L^* = L$
3. $\varepsilon \in L$

where $L^+$ and $L^*$ are the Kleene plus and Kleene star. What exactly is correct here? Does the fact that $\varepsilon \in L$ mean that for every $L$ it is equal to $L^2$?

Comment: I was very confused until I saw the tags. Use should edit the question and explain at least what $L$ is. In general a question should be understandable on its own without having to read neither the title nor the tags.

Comment: edited, please answer my question.

Comment: (well that sounds a bit rude). Okay, so what have you tried? And can you explain what you mean with your last question? I don't understand it...

Comment: I want to know what of all 3 claims can be considered as true based on the fact that $L^2=L$

Comment: So what ideas do you have? This looks like homework, so you have to show a little effort on this site. Do you have guesses for the answers, with or without any proof?

Comment: To get you started, try to construct at least one example of a language that satisfies $L^2=L$ and check the three points on that.

Comment: I think that if L^2 = L then ε∈L and then 1 and 3 is correct .That happens only in case L is not eqaul to empty language, if thats the case only the first is correct, no?

Comment: you have already found a counterexample for 2 and 3. Hint for the first: concatenation is associative: $L^3=(L^2)L$ etc.

Comment: thanks man, you helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, the empty language $\varnothing$ satisfies $\varnothing^2 = \varnothing$ and $\varnothing = \varnothing^+$, but $\varnothing^* = \{ \varepsilon \} \ne \varnothing$.

Next, if the language $L$ is non-empty, it has to contain $\varepsilon$: Say one of the shortest strings in $L$ is $\alpha \ne \varepsilon$, then there are no strings shorter than $\alpha^2$ in $L^2$, a contradiction.

Furthermore, if a non-empty $L = L^2$, then also $L = L \cdot L = L \cdot L^2 = L^3$, and in general $L = L^n$ for $n \ge 1$. Thus:

$\begin{align*}
  L^*
    &= \{ \varepsilon \} \cup L \cup L^2 \cup \ldots \\
    &= \{ \varepsilon \} \cup L \cup L \cup \ldots \\
    &= \{ \varepsilon \} \cup L \\
    &= L \qquad \text{(since \(\varepsilon \in L\))}
\end{align*}$

The same way:

$\begin{align*}
  L^+
    &= L \cup L^2 \cup L^3 \cup \ldots \\
    &= L \cup L \cup L \ldots \\
    &= L
\end{align*}$

Note that for example if $L = \{ \varepsilon, a \}$ then $L^2 = \{ \varepsilon, a, a^2 \} \ne L^2$. Tracing the above discussion, you see that any language sastisfying $L^2 = L$ must be $\varnothing$, $\{ \varepsilon \}$, or be infinite.

Comment: Nice, however there is one exception (as the asker noted in a comment): the empty language $L=\varnothing$ also satisfies $L^2=L$ but does not contain $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @hgmath, right. Ooops. Fixed. Thanks!